# Finding a specific character in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

So let's say I have an array that looks like this:

```
weather = ["sun", "clouds", "rain", "hail", "snow"]
```

And I want to find and display all of the strings which have the letter "s" in them. This is what I think I should do...

```
for(var i = 0; i < weather.length; i++)
{
    if(weather[i].indexOf('s') != -1)
    {
        alert(weather);
    }
}
```

But that just displays all of the weather strings as many times as there are strings with the letter "s" in them. (It will just alert: "sun, clouds, rain, hail, snow" 3 times)

How do I get it to alert just the specific names of the weather which contain the letter "s"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do `alert(weather[i])` instead of `alert(weather)`

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AuJHa/)

Answer (score 5):

as simple modern solution without vars or loops:

```
alert(
  ["sun", "clouds", "rain", "hail", "snow"].filter(/./.test, /i/)
)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what is going on inside .filter()? (the forward slash, the _.test_, the _i_ ) Thanks!

Comment: the 1st argument, `/./.test` points to a callback method, in this case `RegExp.prototype.test()`. It uses a throw-away temp var to point to the method instead of going around the horn and mentioning the constructor (all of a constructor's methods are the same on all instances anyway, so it's just a shortcut). The 2nd arg sets a `this` context for the callback, in this case an instance of a RegExp we want to test against each element of the array. It's split into 2 args because the test() method is _generic_; it doesn't bind `this`, and unspecified, [].filter sets `window` as `this`

Comment: `/./.test == RegExp.prototype.test` is `true`. Also, you can bake-in `this` with `Function.prototype.bind()` to avoid the context loss when passing a method to `[].filter`:  `[5,10,15,20].filter(RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/1/));` Nowadays, fat arrows are so supported and short that it's probably easier to use one like `[5,10,15,20].filter(x=>/1/.test(x));` to implicitly associate the method (test) and the object (a RegExp).

Comment: How can I insert dynamic letter instead of 's'

Answer (score 2):

Oh. I think I was just missing a small detail.

```
for(var i = 0; i < weather.length; i++)
{
    if(weather[i].indexOf('s') != -1)
    {
        alert(weather[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**very simple**

```
 weather = ["sun", "clouds", "rain", "hail", "snow"];

      weather.forEach(function(arrayItem,arrayIndex,array){
              if(array[arrayIndex].match('s')){
               alert(array[arrayIndex]);
              }
      })
```

**Explanation:**

forEach() method calls a function for each element in the array.
arraytItem like='sun' , 'clouds' etc. 
arrayIndex=position of arrayItem;
array=weather;

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit? Explain the idea behind this code for users who might not immediately understand what you are doing here.